# Nginx status page in Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a server which hosts several [Docker](http://docker.io) containers including an Nginx reverse proxy to serve content. In order to get status of this server I have added the following location block:

```
location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log  off;
    allow       127.0.0.1;
    allow       172.0.0.0/8;
    deny        all;
}
```

Under normal circumstances I would only have opened up 127.0.0.1 but that means that the host machine would not have access (only the Nginx container itself would) so I opened up all of the 172 addresses. Is there a cleaner/more secure way of doing this or is my approach reasonable for a production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When docker starts it [creates an interface `docker0` that is an ethernet bridge](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/), and assigns it an IP address. Docker [tries to choose a smart default](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/networkdriver/bridge/driver.go#L58), and the `172.17.0.0/16` range is a good default. The host will route all traffic destined for that network to the `docker0` bridge, and it's not accessible externally unless you've mapped a port.

In your question you've allowed `172.0.0.0/8`, some of which is not [RFC1918 private address space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918). You could restrict this further to either all of the addresses in the Docker network driver source I linked before, or simply `172.17.0.0/16` since that's the first in the list and is usually used.